# SkinnedModelProcessor and models with materials

Tags: c#, xna

I am using XNA 4.0 and Blender 1.6.1. I built a model in Blender, rigged it, used materials to color it, and exported it to .fbx. My model has UV-maps for all the meshes but they do not have textures. When I use the normal model content pipeline with BasicEffects, I can see the model fine (including materials).

However, I then went to use the SkinnedModelProcessor at http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model and now my model is either rendering transparently or not at all.

After looking into the problem, I found the StockEffects tutorial at http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/stock_effects and used it to see how the skinnedeffect was rendering pixels. I changed the pixel shaders (in all applicable places) so that:

```
float color4 = pin.Diffuse;
```

I figured that would allow my model to render correctly without textures with the SkinnedModelProcessor but I cannot figure out how to get the processor to use my updated effect and not the built-in one. If anyone knows how to get the processor to use the updated effect file or another way of getting my model to render using materials and not textures, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your game simply load the Effect file you wrote and then assign it to your Skinned Model

```
public void SetModelEffect(Effect effect)
{
  foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
    foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
    {
      part.Effect = effect;
    }
}
```

hope that helps.